# npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, npm-install, yo

As I was trying to do a MEAN Stack installation on my Windows 10 computer.

My npm version is:

C:\Temp>npm -v
2.7.4

My Node.js version is:

C:\Temp>node --version
v0.12.2

npm install -g yo --prefix C:\yoPackage

(Minor Side question:  I'm trying to specifying the location where I want the packages installed. To elaborate, the aforementioned command specifies C:\yoPackage as the place where I want yo package files to be placed.  What kind of stumbling blocks might I face if I personally specify a installation location for the a package that npm needs to install? )

The problem is that the aforementioned setup commands for yo gives me the following error:
[image]

I ran the following update npm command:

npm -g install npm

However, I still the error in the aforementioned error in the screenshot above.

Could someone please tell me the steps I need to take to resolve the error?

Update:

I just ran the following to set the proxy configuration variable to some empty-like value:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm config set proxy

I also just ran the following clean-up:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm cache clean

I re-installed npm:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -g install npm

Finally I re-ran the yo installation command using npm:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g yo --prefix C:\yoPackage

Here is a screen shot of the output when I ran the aforementioned command:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "deprecated npmconf" stuff is only a warning and is not the source of your problem.

Your problem is the `ECONNRESET` stuff which is an error. As the error message says:

```
This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
and is related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```